# How can I replace values in R data frame by their categories?

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements

Consider e.g. the following data frame:

```
data <- matrix(c(12, 6, 13, 15, 2, 7, 7, 14), nrow = 4)
data <- as.data.frame(data)
```

| Variable 1 | Variable 2 |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | 2 |
| 6 | 7 |
| 13 | 7 |
| 15 | 14 |

Suppose that the values of the Variable 2 are instances of two categories; category 1 (values < 10) and category 2 (values >= 10).

How could I replace the second column by the category of its value? The resulting data frame would be:

| Variable 1 | Variable 2 (Category) |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | Category 1 |
| 6 | Category 1 |
| 13 | Category 1 |
| 15 | Category 2 |

Comment: Use the base function `cut`, it works with whatever number of breaks you need

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse) 

data %>% 
  mutate(across(V2, ~ if_else(.x >= 10, "Category 2", "Category 1")))

     V1 V2        
  <dbl> <chr>     
1    12 Category 1
2     6 Category 1
3    13 Category 1
4    15 Category 2
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know any easy way to do that if I had more than two categories, say, 10 categories?

Answer (score 0):

alternatively with `data.table`

```r
library(data.table)

data <- matrix(c(12, 6, 13, 15, 2, 7, 7, 14), nrow = 4)
data <- as.data.table(data)

format_cat <- function(x){
  case_when(
  x < 10 ~ 'Category 1',
  x >=10 ~ 'Category 2'
  )
}

data[, V2 := format_cat(V2)]
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-25 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

```r
   V1         V2
1: 12 Category 1
2:  6 Category 1
3: 13 Category 1
4: 15 Category 2
```